# Laravel seeder throws error when faking more than 15 records

Tags: php, laravel, sqlite, eloquent, laravel-8

I'm seeding the test database with fake users, posts and categories but for some reason when I seed the database with more than 15 records Laravel throws this error:

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException 

  SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 19 UNIQUE constraint failed: categories.name (SQL: insert into "categories" ("name", "slug", "updated_at", "created_at") values (id, quibusdam-nihil-dignissimos-vitae-sint-minus-est-nostrum, 2021-06-22 17:52:02, 2021-06-22 17:52:02))
```

If I seed 15 or less records at once works fine.

This is the database seeder:

```
User::truncate();
Post::truncate();
Category::truncate();
    
Post::factory(15)->create();
```

The Post factory:

```
public function definition()
    {
        return [
            'user_id' => User::factory(),
            'category_id' => Category::factory(),
            'title' => $this->faker->sentence,
            'slug' => $this->faker->slug,
            'excerpt' => $this->faker->sentence,
            'body' => $this->faker->paragraph
        ];
    }
```

And the category factory:

```
public function definition()
    {
        return [
            'name' => $this->faker->word,
            'slug' => $this->faker->slug
        ];
    }
```

I'm using Laravel 8 and the database is sqlite.

Comment: `$this->faker->word` can only generate so many unique words... It's probably better for your `unique` constraint to be on `slug` instead of `name`. Setting `name` to `This For Example` and `This, For Example` would both be `this-for-example` when slugged, but would bypass the unique `name` constraint.

Comment: Yes it's true so obvious that I didn't see it. Many thanks!

Comment: Haha, no problem; happy to help! I ran into a similar issue recently with generating emails deriving from `$this->factory->first_name` + `$this->factory->last_name` + an email domain; the trouble with randomness is that in some cases it won't fail for 1000+, and others it will fail after 2 rows 